# Limit number of items an observable emit in a period of time

Tags: java, gwt, observable, rx-java, reactivex

Regarding http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takelast.html

I'm trying to limit the number of items in a period of time that an observable emits.
Im pretty sure that the operator I should use is the "takeLast" but for example for this code;

`Observable.range(0,1000).takeLast(5,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(s->Elements.body().add(s+","));`

Im trying to limit the observable with take last as maximum 5 items per second and it works. Although if I call that takeLast operator for an Observable that comes from an event like this:

`RxElemento.fromEvent(it, EventType.keyup).takeLast(5,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(s->Elements.body().add(s+","));`

Where "RxElemento" is an utility class that calls to "addEventListener" of elemental2.dom.EventTarget and "it" is an inputtext, no matter how much I write, it never print.

I think is something like the source is not completed but I dont really end up understanding.

Any tip or orientation?

Thanks!